# How can I get amd64 versions for my i386 packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, 64-bit, 19.10

I've recently found out that running

```
apt list --installed | grep i386 | wc -l
```

Says that I've got 186 i386 packages. Since my system is 64bit, it is probably better to install 64 bit versions instead. So, how do I automatically install amd64 packages instead of my i386 ones, where possible? If there are any way to automatically build the rest which doesn't have prebuilt binaries? I guess some packages can not really be changed, like *wine32* or *steam*, but I suppose most of them can be changed.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. There is always a reason why only i386 packages are there. In most cases they are libraries for 43-bit apps.

Comment: @Pilot6 I guess I can build the apps too? The first line I see in i386 list is gcc, which is definitely not such an app

Comment: Most likely you have 64-bit gcc too.

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 added it to tags

Comment: Can you paste a list at [paste.ubuntu.com](https://paste.ubuntu.com)?